# Expected true to be false error while tesing for not visible in protractor

Tags: protractor, invisible

I delete a row. now I am trying to check that the row is deleted. I tried with:

```
expect(element(by.cssContainingText('.ng-star-inserted','2')).isPresent()).toBe(false);
```

or

```
expect(element(by.cssContainingText('.ng-star-inserted','2')).isDisplayed()).toBe(false);
```

which returns an error

> Expected true to be false

then I tried with :

```
expect(element(by.cssContainingText('.ng-star-inserted','2')).isPresent()).toBeFalsy();
```

which returns an unknown error.
I am not sure what am I doing wrong here. please help.

Comment: Hm, I will be a captain ) Are you sure that item has already been removed? Just put `browser.sleep(5000)` after removal.

Comment: browser.sleep is not working here. it does not solve the problem

Comment: Could you check manually is this element still in the DOM?

Comment: could it be that the next row shifts up and becomes row 2? Guessing here. Please forgive if I am off.

Comment: @Oleksii.. no I did not find it in DOM after delete.

Comment: @JeremyKahan nope each row has individual ID

Comment: I suggest that you have wrong css selector. Because if it returns true then element by this css is visible. Find after deletion this elemenet manually from the console. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I am afraid I don't know how to find element manually. could you please suggest me on that?

Comment: What if you made it " 2 " or "2 " or " 2"? I'm wondering if what you have might be duped by the presence of a "21" or "12"?

Comment: Another way to check might be if before deletion you say var elem=element(by.cssContainingText('.ng-star-inserted','2') does the console say "found multiple elements matching...using the first one"?

Comment: Or might it be a timing thing. if you had var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions; and elem as in my preceding comment, does
browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(elem), 30000,'wait for row deletion to take effect'); fail? If not, adding it before your expect() would fix it. If it does fail, @Oleksii must be right that really something matching it is there. In that case try putting a browser.sleep(5*60*1000) before the expect, then right clicking and inspecting yourself interactively (possibly browser.pause() allows that, too)

Comment: @JeremyKahan you are right. it says...more than one element found... the first result will be used. I think I got the problem.

Comment: thanks a lot to both of you...@Oleksii and @JeremyKahan for your precious time and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that the expect statement was not correct here. it was showing a message like

> more than one element found....

which was the main cause of the error.

so, what I did to overcome the problem is, declare a variable and then use that in the validation part.

```
let removedItem = element(by.cssContainingText('.ng-star-inserted', '6701202609675'));
.
.
.
expect((removedItem).isPresent('6701202609675')).toBe(false);
```